# Server only alow few specific ipaddresses from clients

Tags: c#, sockets

I have already known server can accept one specific client's IPaddress or all IPaddress if I set IPaddress.Any

```
IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port);
Bind(localEndPoint);
```

but I want my server only allows few client's IPaddresses such as "192.168.1.1" and "127.0.0.1" 
 the other ip isn't allowed
how to do that?

Comment: Use the right tools for the job? Why take this kind of responsibility into your code rather than just configuring a firewall rule?

Comment: thanks but i don't want to config firewall